# What is with this black line?

Tags: brutal-legend

During a cut-scene, I noticed an odd black line.  It seemed to be locked on a point in a specific character's neck and went off (no idea how far but always past the viewpoint of the screen) in the direction the character was facing.

I've only seen it on this character and have don't remember her in the next few cut-scenes.

Here are a couple pictures to illustrate:

[image: Muppet]

[image: Black sniper laser]

What is this?  How can I make it go away?

Comment: Oww, that looks like a graphical artefact. It indicates that something's wrong with your graphics card. Check if it throws up any errors with ATItool. It may just be sitting loosely in its slot or overheating (jostle it a little and clean the cooler. Don't forget to turn off you computer before you do either). If that doesn't help, it may be time to start looking for a replacement.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann Not necessarily the graphics card. This is caused by one (or more) mesh triangles having improperly placed vertices. This can be caused by a failing graphics card, sure, but it can also be caused by bugs in the game, which is far, far more likely the cause. Given it's associated with a particular character in a particular scene, her model probably includes a bad mesh in this scene.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie True, that's a possibility. But in my experience so far, artefacting tended to be fairly consistent early on, occuring in the same objects. While I don't remember if this particular scene had anything wrong when I played, I still suggest running some basic diagnostics, just to be safe.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann  I would doubt it is the graphics card as it is just under a year old.  For information purposes, it is a [Geforce GTX 560 Ti](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-560ti).

Comment: @Batophobia Fair enough. I would certainly hope it's not a hardware problem. It's still a possible warning sign, so do run some diagnostics just in case. If the problem's in the game itself, there isn't much you can do, unfortunately - developers' fault, not yours. Check if it's patched up, stop forcing graphics settings in NVidia control settings, and poke around in the game's own settings.

Comment: I saw the same artifact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black lines from characters faces (Lita in this case) was/is a bug in the game [acknowledged by the developer](http://steamcommunity.com/app/225260/discussions/0/846945411136957220/#c846946775290013559). It doesn't look like was ever fixed. I don't remember seeing it though when I played through so maybe it was just on some video cards.